# Counter Intuitive Probability Of Coin Game

Tags: probability, statistics

John and Mary toss a fair coin **alternately**. The first one to get Heads wins the game.

**John goes first**. What are the odds that John will win?

Basically the way I calculated this is :

1. $P(W_i)$ stands for John wins on his $i_{th}$ try
2. John wins on his first try with $P(W_1) = \frac{1}{2}$
3. John wins on his second try with $P(W_2) = \frac{1}{2^3}$
4. John wins on his third try with $P(W_3) = \frac{1}{2^5}$
5. John wins on his fourth try with $P(W_4) = \frac{1}{2^7}$
6. $...$
7. John wins on his $k_{th}$ try with $P(W_k) = \frac{1}{2^{2k-1}}$

So the probability in question is : $\sum^{i=k}_{i=1} 1/2^{2i-1}$
which ***seems*** to converge to 0.666666 which is $66.6$%. and seems counter - intuitive to me as I expected a probability around $50$%

Comment: Going first gives a *large* advantage.  Half of the time Mary never even gets to flip her coin!

Comment: Well, supposing they are alternating tossing the coin, it makes sense since he is the first to play.

Comment: Expecting 50:50 is only reasonable if there is an equal chance of players winning. Since John wins half the games immediately, it should be clear why his chances are better than that  The calculations are just detail bearing this out. Consider also the iterative game and what chance of winning Mary would have - this should further clarify why it's actually 2:1.

Comment: It's a geometric progression, there's a formula for it, it converges to $2/3$.

Comment: I guess the question is why should you intuition be true or false.  The intuition is a head is just as likely to occur at any time so it should be even.  But we aren't asking when *a* head occurs.  We are asking when the *first* head occur.  I suppose we might think "well, a head is as likely to occur the first time on any times as any else" but if we thing about it just a little bit the probablity the first head is on a late flip is a lot rarer than it occuring on an early flip as occurring on a late flip means there most be *many* tails in a row but an early flip is just a few. ... so...

Comment: ... so Johns flips, 1,3,5, 7 are all earlier than each of Mary's flips 2,4,6,8.  The firs head is more likely to occur in the first flip than the second, more likely to occur in the 3rd than the 4th, etc.  So... now, it should be intuitive that John has a distinct advantage.  Mary's not out of the running.  *IF* john doesn't win immediately the advantage is hers but John has a 50% chance of winning in the first flip. Actually now intuitive if Johns probability of winning is $X$ then that should be ..... tbc.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment and you already have the correct way of solving.  This is just a comment about why it should or should not be intuitive that the probability should or shouldn't be 50%.

....

The reason is it seems intuitive that John and Mary are equally likely to win is because it is reasonable to assume the first HEAD is as likely to occur on any flip as any other.

But if we think about that, that is absolutely *not* true.  After all, for the first HEAD to occur on the $20$th flip (meaning the first $19$ flips were *all* tails) is a lot less likely then the first head occurring on, say, the third flip (which would only require the first two flips were tails).

In fact the probability the first HEAD occurring on the $k$th flip (requiring $k-1$ tails in a row) is twice as likely as the first HEAD occurring on the $k+1$th flip (requiring $k$ tails in a row).

So if you think about it John winning on the the first flip is twice as likely as Mary winning on the second flip.  And John winning on the third flip is twice as likely as Mary winning on the fourth flip. And so on.

So, actually, intuitively John's probability of winning should be twice the probability of Mary winning.

And it is!

If John probability of winning when he goes first is $X$.  Then if the first flip is TAILS and it is Marys turn (there is a $\frac 12$ probability of that) then it should now be that the probability that Mary will win should be exactly the same $X$ but *after the first flip was tails*.  So if Johns probability of winning is $X$ then Mary's probability should be $\frac 12x$ and so $X + \frac 12 X=1$ and we should have $X = \frac 23$.

And we do!

Answer (score 2):

Count a round as John flips, Mary flips (unless John won).

At the beginning of any given round, John has a $.5$ chance of winning during that round; and Mary has a $.25$ chance of winning during that round. (The remaining $.25$ probability gives the chance of going to another round).

So given that someone won in a certain round, the probability of it being John is twice as great as the probability of it being Mary. So John wins $\frac23$ of the time (twice as often as Mary). Your problem wording asks for odd. The odds of John winning are $2$ to $1$.

It's perhaps interesting to note that if Mary flips a coin that always comes up heads, then the game would be fair. (Although not very interesting--if John flips heads John wins; otherwise Mary wins.)

Answer (score 1):

With probability 1, either John or Mary will   win the game eventually.  Let $p$ denote the probability that John will win  the game.  If his first toss yields heads, the game is over. If he gets tails, then his chance of winning will be the same as Mary's at the start of the game, namely, $1-p$.
Thus $$p=1/2+ (1-p)/2$$
and the solution is $p=2/3$.